# Push Smook's response to Sequence

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I've used Smook Mediator in WSO2ESB to transform content in 'plain/text' to 'XML'. I don't know the output is pushed to sequence by default or not. So I tried to send output of Smook to a WS by Send Mediator like this, but nothing's happended. This is my PS's configuration:

```
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <smooks config-key="conf:/smooksccconfig.xml">
            <input type="text"/>
            <output type="xml"/>
         </smooks>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send receive="Testing">
            <endpoint key="GeoEP"/>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
```

Is there any needed mediator to push result of transformation to the Sequence?
Can u give me some advises?

Thank,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems fine. You don't need any mediator to push the results of Smooks transformation to a sequence. Anyway to figure out the error you can enable wirelogs in ESB. Please do the following steps.

- Shotdown the ESB instance
- Locate log4j.properties file under $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory
- Uncomment the line `log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG`
- Then restart the ESB instance
- symbol << represents contents going out of the ESB where as >> represents things comes into the ESB

Also please check whether your logfull mediator logs the correct output after the transformation. If that is the case, then you have to look into your endpoint config.

If you have any error messages in ESB console, then please attach them here so that we can have some more insight into your issue using them.